# how to solve the issue that eclipse notes "Unable to open file /application.yml for writing" on Mac

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I have import a Spring Project by Eclipse on Mac,and it notes that i don't have the limit to open the application.yml to write when application loaded finish.I don't have any solution about it.And anyone know how it occur and how can i resolve the issue?
[image]   Thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: Please show the directory layout of your application....and apart from that the tag `<parent>` shows that something is wrong ...likely with your parent...

Comment: your means is that there get something with parents?but i can be loaded and running normally on windows10.I don't know whether it has the relationship with the difference between MacOS and Windows.but i really goes well on Windows Platform.

Comment: I don't want to see the package structure I wanted to see the directory structure (project view i Eclipse)...

Comment: so sorry for my mistake.  The directory structure the same as package‘s. is it right? thus i want to know why it can running on windows10 and get errors on mac.